# Common datatype for multiple blocks

Tags: go

Consider this case/logic:

```
// You can edit this code!
// Click here and start typing.
package main

func main() {
    foo := 0
    test := 1

    if test > 1 {
        foo = 1
    } else {
        foo = "2"
    }

    fmt.Printf("%s", foo)
}
```

The idea is to have a common variable for different if statement blocks that can hold all datatypes.

Not much. New to golang.

Comment: The language is called Go and you do not write this type of code. While Go is not about creating elaborate type _hierarchies_ you have to model your problem with sensible, static types, possible interfaces for polymorphism. Don't try to do dynamic typing like e.g. in Python.

Answer (score 4):

Use type `any` to hold values of all datatypes.

```
var foo any
test := 1

if test > 1 {
    foo = 1
} else {
    foo = "2"
}

fmt.Printf("%v", foo)
```

https://go.dev/play/p/fQvPyjfOtV3

Comment: Cool. Thanks. What if foo is an array and I assign different types of arrays to foo in different blocks? How will you respond then.

Comment: I would respond that you should use type `any`.  https://go.dev/play/p/ueOXhlg7VTP

Comment: Nice. Thanks. One more follow up then:

It seems like you can not run range on any variable. Then?

Comment: You keep moving the goal posts for this question!  https://go.dev/play/p/CsYtRRmhgfa or https://go.dev/play/p/KNVVJzXX0DP

Comment: I would like to add that using `any` (an alias for `interface{}`) comes with its own problems and is often just a lazy measure instead of defining proper interfaces for your use cases.

Comment: The use case in the question is calling fmt.Printf.  There's nothing wrong with passing a variable of type `any` to the fmt.Printf argument with type `any`.

Answer (score 0):

Go is statically typed. That is one of its undeniable strengths.

You MAY use the empty interface `interface{}` (aka `any`), but that usually is a bad idea.

```golang
func main() {
    var foo interface{}
    test := 1

    if test > 1 {
        foo = 1
    } else {
        foo = "2"
    }
    fmt.Printf("%#v", foo)
}
```

A much better idea is to use interfaces properly

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

// MyInt is a type that is an alias for int
type MyInt int

// String is a method that returns the string representation of the MyInt.
// It satisfies the fmt.Stringer interface.
func (m MyInt) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("%d", m)
}

// MyString is a type that is an alias for string.
type MyString string

// String is a method that returns the string representation of the MyString.
// It satisfies the fmt.Stringer interface.
func (m MyString) String() string {
    return string(m)
}

func main() {

    // Here is where the "magic" happens:
    // You define someValue as fmt.Stringer
    // which means that it can take all types which
    // happen to satisfy the fmt.Stringer interface.
    // Note that there is no "implements fmt.Stringer"
    // as in Go, interfaces are implicitly checked at
    // compile time.
    var someValue fmt.Stringer

    test := 1

    if test > 1 {
        someValue = MyInt(5)
    } else {
        someValue = MyString("Hello")
    }

    fmt.Printf("%s\n", someValue.String())

    // Output: Hello

    // Say you want to find out what type someValue is at runtime.

    switch someValue.(type) {
    case MyInt:
        fmt.Println("someValue is a MyInt")
    case MyString:
        fmt.Println("someValue is a MyString")
    default:
        fmt.Println("someValue is something else")
    }
}
```

While this approach may seem a bit tedious at first, it is MUCH cleaner. Basically, you are creating a contract:

> The value of this var needs to conform to the behavior defined in the interface `fmt.Stringer`.

Or, of course, any other interface you may define.

---

## Off topic

Since you mentioned that you are new to Go, here are some suggestions for you

1. [Effective Go](https://go.dev/doc/effective_go): A boatload of information on how to write good Go programs
2. [Go proverbs](https://go-proverbs.github.io): A collection of mantras for Go programmers with (more or less) detailed video explanations when you click on the respective proverb. The video explaining them all is 23 minutes long and watching it is time well invested.
3. [Go by example](https://gobyexample.com): Well... That should be selfexplanatory.